# TFS Gated Check-In Partially Succeeded (Check-In Committed)

Tags: c#, exception, nullreferenceexception, checkin

So I have the following screenshots when I checked in:

[image]

I was looking around the internet and they seem to have a problem with their test, so I took a look at mine:

[image]

There are no failed tests, except there is an error System.NullReferenceException..

Why does this partially succeed happen? I didn't touch this class (where it gets the error) I did made a test for it, so is this is what is causing it?

Comment: It looks like you have a race condition. That's about all anyone's going to be able to tell you without seeing the test code and the code under test.

Comment: Basically I am testing a singleton class with Thread t = new Thread(Worker); t.Start()

Since it's hard to test it being a multithreaded environment, I used reflection to access the private instance and set it to null again per TestMethod, but I guess it's bad tests, but it does make the tests pass

Comment: Yup, it does seem like a race condition, everything is ok now, thanks a bunch..